# Java parameter value changes itself

Tags: java

Today, while writing a simple program, I found some strange behaviour.
I wrote simple sorting method in which returns another sorted array.

```
public double[] sortMe(double[] array) 
{
    double[] narray=new double[array.length];
    narray=array;
    for(int i=0;i<narray.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<narray.length;j++)
        {
            if(narray[i]<narray[j])
            {
                double temp=narray[i];
                narray[i]=narray[j];
                narray[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return narray;
}
```

In my driver class, when I called this sortMe method, it updated my testArray as well. Since testArray is out of scope for sortMe method, then when testArray got sorted ?

```
double [ ] testArray = {3, 6, 2, 5, 8, 4, 1, 7};
double [ ] results;
results = af.sortMe(testArray);
af.printMe(results);
```

Comment: Please read about 'Pass by Value' and 'Pass by Reference'. That would answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: Check this out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `sortMe` method, you are assigning the reference of `array` to `narray` using `narray=array;`.

This means now `narray` is pointing to the same array as `array`, and so if you modify `narray`, array is also changed and since array just has a reference to `testArray` passed to the method, `testArray` is also sorted.

If you do not want testArray to change, when assigning the `array` to `narray`, use `System.arraycopy()` to copy the values of `array` to `narray`. Change it as shown below.

```
System.arraycopy(array,0,narray,0,array.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think these lines do:

```
double[] narray=new double[array.length];
narray=array;
```

It creates a new array, which is then immediately discarded, and assigned the same instance as the parameter array.

If you want to return a new array, either use it in a constructor, or manually copy the fields from array A to array B. Since you're doing a sort, you probably don't even need to do this.